# Ng2-charts set color for one specific value in dataset

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

As you can see

[image]

I have second dataset, and for 1st and 4th values in it i need red color, for all other - blue, how can i implement this via ng2-charts, or had anyone seen library, which solves this task. i've tried to add 3rd dataset, and hide values in second with null, but there is a gap between not null values then

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[ng2-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts) uses itself [Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js). The bar chart dataset property [`backgroundColor`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties) can be defined as a `string` or an `array` of strings.

Therefore, in your `component` class, you can define `chartColors` as follows:

```
chartColors = [
  {
    backgroundColor: "green"
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: ["red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "red"]
  }
];
```

In the HTML template, `chartColors` needs to be referenced as shown below:

```
<canvas baseChart  
  ...
  [colors]="chartColors">
</canvas>
```

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-distinct-colors?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and see how it works.